# Android: how to move marquee in the same direction as the text

Tags: android, textview, marquee

I would like my marquee to move from right to left when it contains a text in a left-to-right locale (like western languages), and left to right when it contains right-to-left locale (like hebrew or arabic). 
I found other questions bout textview marquee direction, with all kinds of hacks but without the connection to the locale writing.
Normally this should be filed as a bug to Google...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the user's language is RTL or not. There is different ways to achieve this. It looks like [BidiFormatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/text/BidiFormatter.html) added recently in the Compatibility Package looks like a simple option. You can then set the marquee programatically with [setEllipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEllipsize%28android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt%29)

It should look something like this :

```
if (bidiFormatter.isRtlContext()) {
   textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.BEGIN);
} else {
   textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. Yet another answer I missed because of lame notification system... I really have to check whether notifications go to spam.